# Can I find and apply PatternFill to all blank (empty cells) in a worksheet with openpxl

Tags: formatting, styles, openpyxl, is-empty

Newbie! Please be gentle. 
I'm trying to save a worksheet using openpyxl with some formatting.

I have blank/empty cells in my worksheet and I would like to format/fill them.

So. Find all blank/empty cells
Apply PatternFill

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font
from openpyxl.styles import Fill, Color

catalogwb = openpyxl.load_workbook(currentDir + fileName)
catalogws = catalogwb.active
catalogws1 = catalogwb.create_sheet("Sheet2")

testcell = catalogws['B2']
testcell.fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor="DDDDDD") #works!

max_row=catalogws.max_row
max_col=catalogws.max_column
print(max_row , max_col)

catalogws.column_dimensions['B'].width = 80

myFill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor="DDDDDD")
catalogws.cell(row=max_row,column=max_col).fill = myFill #works!
```

Spent too much time on this. 
Thanks!

Comment: So, if the fill works, what exactly is the problem?